# Publish Subscribe Foreign Exchange Channel

Tags: redis

I have quite a strange question..

Has anyone setup a Publish/Subscribe Foreign Currency Exchange server???

I know that redis can perform the PUB/SUB.. but i need a channel or a better idea :D

Any suggestions welcome..

**Update:** A publish/subscribe to even Google / Yahoo Api's is also an option..
I just dont want to query every time i need information.. ( i need to maintain it locally )
Wherby the "Publisher/Provider" broadcasts it to me as information changes..

Think Comet,Websockets,Pubsubhubbub etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll bet money that the answer to your question is "no".  As for alternate ideas: if you want to get this information from the horse's mouth, use the FOREX APIs: http://www.forex.com/forex-api.html.  I've never looked into what they cost.  If that's overkill, try the Google Finance APIs.

Comment: Well your definitely right.. everyone wants money that ive seen..

Besides Yahoo and Google API's which i believe i can use for free ( ive already looked into this )